# Stuck with Query Result

Tags: mysql, sql

Would really appreciate it if someone could help me with my query.

Below is a sample table in which I want to retrieve those ActionId's which are not repeated twice or more.
I've tried **not in**, **count**, and **distinct** but no luck so far.

Required: Product=AA, OrderType=Market, ActionId=Non Repeated ones
[image: sample table]

```
select distinct ActionId,LocationId,PartyName from order where ActionIid in (select distinct ActionId from order where Product = 'AA'and OrderStatus = 'Complete') order by ActionId desc
```

```
select ActioId from order where  Product ='AA'
and OrderType='Market'
and ActioId not in (
select ntd_id from order where  Product ='AA'
and OrderType!='Limit'
and OrderType!='Stop'
group by ActioId having count(*)<2
)
group by ActionId
```

Where am I making the mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 3):

You want all the actionid appears once in the table for which product='AA' and ordertype='Market'. I have edited my answer. Please check:

```
select ActionId from order 
group by actionid 
having count(*)=1 and max(Product) ='AA' and max(OrderType)='Market'
```

Comment: You just beat me to it, i have almost the same anwser.

Comment: Our answers might helped him. Cheers!

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur I've already tried with this one, it does give me the output for the first 6 rows but after that, the ActionId's are those which are repeated twice or thrice available in other OrderType

Comment: I have changed my answer. Please check now.

Comment: Still not getting what is required

Comment: Please share your required output so that I can check first.

Answer (score 1):

I have no time to test this but this is how I would go fro this. It should only give you the `ActioId` that is only once in the table.

```
SELECT 
    `ActioId` 
FROM `order `
WHERE 
   Product = 'AA' 
   AND 
   OrderType = 'Market' 
GROUP BY 
   `ActioId` 
HAVING 
    count(ActioId) < 2 
ORDER BY 
   `ActioId` ASC
```

Comment: this query gives me ActionId from both the Product

Comment: After Having count(ActioId) < 2 and max(Product) = 'AA'

Comment: Or use: WHERE Product  = 'AA' AND OrderType = 'Market' I have changed the answer

Comment: Is this working for you?, You do not have slected the anwser that is working for you.